# Need advice on getting my code to work (linking a javascript function to an html element)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I'm playing around with linking JavaScript to HTML and creating event listeners and I stumbled upon an issue with my code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quote randomizer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="switchy">Click me</p>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"> </script>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const sentences = ["I am the first sentence", "Second sentence reporting in", "I am the third one", "Hello there"];

const randomIndex = Math.round(math.random()*3);

function clicky() {
  document.getElementById("switchy").innerHTML = "sentences[randomIndex]"";
}

document.getElementById("switchy").addEventListener("click", clicky);
```

What I want from it is to replace the text that's already written in HTML with a random string from a premade array, through a random function . However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why it's not working.

Comment: Too many quotes in `"sentences[randomIndex]"";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a functioncall to get the random number.  I'm assuming that you want 0, 1, 2 and 3 to be possible results since the array contains 4 elements.

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const sentences = ["I am the first sentence", "Second sentence reporting in", "I am the third one", "Hello there"];

function clicky() {
  document.getElementById("switchy").innerHTML = sentences[getRandomInt(3)];
}

document.getElementById("switchy").addEventListener("click", clicky);
```

```html
<p id="switchy">Click me</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Found two problems:

1. `Math` !== `math`
2. Do not put quote marks around a variable

```js
const sentences = ["I am the first sentence", "Second sentence reporting in", "I am the third one", "Hello there"];

const randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*3);

function clicky() {
  document.getElementById("switchy").innerHTML = sentences[randomIndex];
}

document.getElementById("switchy").addEventListener("click", clicky);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quote randomizer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="switchy">Click me</p>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're `math.random()` needs to be `Math.random()`. Move `randomIndex` into the `click()` function, so it randomizes on each click of "Click Me". Also, `document.getElementById("switchy").innerHTML = "sentences[randomIndex]"";` should be `document.getElementById("switchy").innerHTML = sentences[randomIndex];` No quotes around the array variable. I added an additional paragraph element so you can see the sentences randomly appear on clicking of "Click Me".

```js
const sentences = ["I am the first sentence", "Second sentence reporting in", "I am the third one", "Hello there"];

function clicky() {
  let randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
  document.getElementById("sentence-text").innerHTML = sentences[randomIndex];
}

document.getElementById("switchy").addEventListener("click", clicky);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Quote randomizer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="sentence-text"></p>
  <p id="switchy">Click me</p>
</body>

</html>
```